# FIlter an Object based on a key and get the value for that key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have an input and typed hosu so what I want to be able to do is filter through this objects and get the value for it.So I should get 321234 which is the pincode for hosurRoad. How do i achieve this?

```
const recoganizedAreas = {
  'hsr':'560102',
  'bypanahalli':'676667',
  'marathalli':'667776',
  'hosurRoad':'321236',
  'teachersColony':'560101'
};

const areas = Object.keys(recoganizedAreas);
```

Comment: I expect you mean 321236 instead of 321234

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `recoganizedAreas[ areas[3] ]` to get value for `hosurRoad of recoganizedAreas`

Also you can reach of `3` for hosurRoad of areas by using `areas.indexOf("hosurRoad")`

```
console.log(recoganizedAreas[ areas[3] ])
"321236"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the key and access the value from Object directly.

```js
const text = 'hosu';
const recoganizedAreas = {
  'hsr':'560102',
  'bypanahalli':'676667',
  'marathalli':'667776',
  'hosurRoad':'321236',
  'teachersColony':'560101'
};

const key = Object.keys(recoganizedAreas).find(key => key.includes(text));
if(recoganizedAreas[key]) {
    console.log(recoganizedAreas[key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the request because if you have an object you can just access the property you are looking for.

If you have to do some business logic based on key value you can use Object.entries to filter the object by key

here some example

```js
const recoganizedAreas = {
  'hsr':'560102',
  'bypanahalli':'676667',
  'marathalli':'667776',
  'hosurRoad':'321236',
  'teachersColony':'560101'
};

const areas = Object.keys(recoganizedAreas)

const hosurPinCode = recoganizedAreas.hosurRoad

console.log(hosurPinCode)

const objectFilteredByKey = (key) => Object.fromEntries(
Object.entries(recoganizedAreas).filter(([k, _]) => k === key)
)
   
console.log(objectFilteredByKey('hosurRoad'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you are looking for

```js
const recoganizedAreas = {
  'hsr':'560102',
  'bypanahalli':'676667',
  'marathalli':'667776',
  'hosurRoad':'321236',
  'teachersColony':'560101'
};

const typed = 'hosu'
const foundKey = Object.keys(recoganizedAreas).find(key => key.includes(typed))
const foundValue = recoganizedAreas[foundKey] || "Not found"

console.log(foundValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the question too thoroughly but I think you can just use ones if the following:

```
Object.values(obj)
// Or
Object.entries(obj)
```